# The Spelling of Movie

Tags: grammar, spelling

Why is movie not spelt like movy?
I thought all nouns that end in "y" should be changed into "ie" when it's a plural.

Comment: Really? Are there *rules* about how one thing is spelled?!

Comment: I'd guess because it qualifies as a diminutive, like Howard becomes Howie, not Howy. 2nd point monkey doesn't gain an 'ie' when plural… so it ends up being a bit like the "I before E except after C" which has more exceptions than agreements in English ;)

Comment: Your "rule" does not apply to "movie" since it doesn't end in "y". You can pick the plural nouns ending in "ys" out of this list [Words ending in ys in the Litscape default word list](http://www.litscape.com/words/ending_with/s/ys_end_words.html). Seems your thought is wrong.

Comment: Exactly what noun ending in -y are you thinking is relevant here? *Movie* is derived from the verb *move* via the phrase *moving picture*; there's no 'y' involved anywhere.

Comment: Regrettably, there are few invariable rules of spelling in English -- *ghoti* (q.v.) could spell *fish* according to English orthography (attributed to George Bernard Shaw).

Comment: While we're on the subject, let's not forget about _cookie, brownie, moxie, pixie, prairie_, and _rookie_.

Comment: @Tetsujin - ["i before e"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/i-before-e-except-after-c) has fewer exceptions than you might think, if we can remember that the "rule" is only intended to be applied in words where the two vowels combine to make the *long* *e* sound. (Even then, though, the so-called rule isn't foolproof. Weird, isn't it?)

Comment: @J.R. I actually got the 'more exceptions' bit from QI, so never really questioned/researched it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the logic behind your question, you are asking:

Since **movies** is plural, why is the singular *movie* and not *movy*?

In general:

Well, just because there is a [common and helpful rule](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/plural-nouns/) that states

> A noun ending in a *consonant* and then *y* makes the plural by dropping the *y* and adding *-ies*

this does not mean that you can always apply this rule backwards to **any** plural word ending in *-ies* to get the singular of that word.

That is, there is no rule that says a word whose plural form ends in *-ies* comes from a singular form that ends in *consonant* plus *-y*.

You can apply the rule backwards, when it was originally to a word, as in

daisies : daisy
ponies : pony

But you cannot apply the rule backwards when it was not originally applied. Thus the following does not work

monies : mony

(Note that *money* has two plural forms, *moneys* and *monies*.)

**In Particular**

And the following does not work:

movies : movy

Because the singular of *movies* is not *movy* but *movie*.  The **why** of that has to do with *[movie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=movie&allowed_in_frame=0)* coming from *moving picture*. Mov(ing picture).

The *-ing picture* was replaced by the ending *[-ie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ie?)*. I suppose it could have been replaced by *y* (after all, we have such nouns as *gravy*.

I suspect that *movie(s)* originally had a diminutive meaning, in which case **the ending [-y](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-y) seems to be fine only in words whose last consonant is doubled** (doggy, granny) while *-ie* goes with those kind of words (doggie, grannie) *or*...

> **with words whose consonants are not doubled** (sweetie, birdie). I guess *movvy* didn't quite work, any more than *movy*.

A similar word to *movie*, now outdated, is

**talkie**

It has the plural *talkies*. The word *[talkie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=talkie&allowed_in_frame=0)* apparently does not come directly from *talking pictures*, but from *movies*. The *mov-* was replaced by *talk-*.

Note that we have '[walkie-talkie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=walkie-talkie&allowed_in_frame=0)'. This conforms with *-ie* usage in words whose ending consonant does not double. But later on came the form 'walky-talky'. One can only guess why this variant spelling came about.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I've never heard or read "monies" or "moneys" before. Could you use it in a sentence?

Comment: @Zgialor There are some examples in the ODO at [Definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/money)

Comment: @Zgialor, In addition, see usage at Google Ngram: [`* monies,* moneys`](http://bit.ly/1ATw76w)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Hm, interesting. Looks like it's usage has largely declined over the years, but not that much (although the sudden increasing trend for "moneys" from 2004 to 2008 is interesting). Perhaps I have seen it before, but I didn't think it was that significant, so the instance wasn't stored in my long-term memory.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the singular **-ie** ending is a common way to make a [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) name for someone or something in English. It [came from](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231083) Scots dialect in the 1600s. Some examples:

> **cookie**, **[mousie](http://www.robertburns.org/works/75.shtml)**, **lassie**, **Annie** (diminutive for Ann), **Carrie** (diminutive for Caroline), **Charlie** (diminutive for Charles), and many more

It's not consistent, though. Some of these diminutives are spelled with **-y** in the singular:

> **baby**, **mommy**, **daddy**, **puppy**, **kitty**, **Johnny** (diminutive for John), and many more

Some are spelled both ways. For example, **Johnnie**.

The word **movie** is short for "moving picture". The Oxford English Dictionary lists [one](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123038) instance of **movy**, from [George Bernard Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bernard_Shaw)'s play *[Heartbreak House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbreak_House),* written in 1919:

> "Talk like a man, not a **movy**."

But that spelling is long gone. As for *why* the "movie" spelling prevailed over "movy", that is probably unknown and unknowable today.

Answer (score -1):

"Movie" [was derived from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=movie) "moving picture", which already had the "i".

Comment: And because the meta discussion is still fresh in my mind here's a quick supporting citation: [Origin 1905-10; mov(ing picture) + -ie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/movie). I don't think the -ie was added because moving had an "i" in it though. I think it's more along the lines of "selfie" or "[wedgie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wedgie)".

Comment: "selfie" and "wedgie" date from well after "movie".  Their "ie"s might be derived by analogy to "movie"'s "ie".

Comment: It's possible. I did see some mention of -ie becoming more popular than -y when I was looking at the etymology. I don't know if it's attributable to movie or not. I wasn't able to find much in the brief search I did.

Comment: @ColleenV Guys, I think it's *doggy* versus *movvy* when it comes to *-y* or *-ie*. Some consonants don't take to doubling. Also *sweetie*, *birdie* (a **pre-movie** word), not *sweetty*, *birdy*, *sweettie*, *birddie*. An allowable doubled consonant can take either (*doggie*, *grannie*).